# How to put onClick in column of data tables?

Tags: reactjs, datatables

So, been trying to use datatable in reactjs, I want to put an onclick in the column but getting an error.

Following is my code:

```
const $ = require('jquery')
$.DataTable = require('datatables.net')
class Rmsdatatable extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handletableclick = this.handletableclick.bind(this)
    }
    handletableclick(event) {
        console.log(event)
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log(this.props.data)
        this.$el = $(this.el)
        this.$el.DataTable(
            {
                data: this.props.data,
                scrollY: 520,
                paging: false,
                responsive: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: "vfdSno",
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return '<a onClick={' + this.handletableclick.bind(this, row) + '} >' + data + '</a>'
                        }
                    },
                    { data: "customerName" },
                    { data: "district" },
                    { data: "state" }
                ]
            }
        )
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ 'padding': '10px' }} className="col-xs-10">
                <table id="example" className="display" width="100%" ref={el => this.el = el}>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>VFD/Controller No</th>
                            <th>Beneficiary</th>
                            <th>District</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead></table>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

For reference, I am using this link:

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/38969/reload-refresh-table-after-event

Error is : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'handletableclick' of undefined`

Thanks and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 8):

can you try like this:

```
 columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: 1,
                createdCell: (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) =>
                  ReactDOM.render(
                    <button
                      onClick={() => this.handletableclick(row) }>
                     data
                    </button>, td),
              } 
        ]
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted by the person who asked the question. Because i faced same issue and at that the "createdCell" did the work for me.

Comment: This is the correct solution for this issue. It took me ages to find this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
return (<a onClick={ this.handletableclick.bind(this, row) }>{ data }</a>)
```

Replace current return statement with the one from above. You don't need to return a string of your html tag.

Comment: Just remove handletableclick function from component and create it as a:

const handletableclick = () => {  // do your thing }

Than call it without this.

Comment: Tried. no luck.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
       "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
            {
       $(ntd).html("<a onClick={ this.handletableclick.bind(this, iRow)}>{ 
              sData }</a>
              }
```

instead of

```
render: function (data, type, row) {
     return '<a onClick={' + 
   this.handletableclick.bind(this, row) + '} >' + data + '</a>'
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a scope issue. Try the following:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log(this.props.data)
        this.$el = $(this.el)
        const self = this; // ******** save a reference to 'this' 
        this.$el.DataTable(
            {
                data: this.props.data,
                scrollY: 520,
                paging: false,
                responsive: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: "vfdSno",
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            // ******** use self here (instead of this) ********
                            return '<a onClick={' + self.handletableclick.bind(self, row) + '} >' + data + '</a>'
                        }
                    },
                    { data: "customerName" },
                    { data: "district" },
                    { data: "state" }
                ]
            }
        )
    }
```

Comment: can you upload a live code example that reproduces this issue? this will help us find the issue quickly